# Why are atomic counters and images referred as uniforms when they are actually not uniform?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Atomic counters and images can be written to in shaders... so they are not constant(uniform).

Why are they called uniforms then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You are thinking of `uniform` from the wrong perspective.

While true that uniforms are constant, their more important characteristic is that they provide... *uniform* variable storage across all invocations of a shader. `uniform` is after all, nothing but a storage qualifier, the same as `in` or `out`.

#### Both of the data types you mention belong to a special class GLSL refers to as ***opaque***:

1. `atomic_uint`

   - References a location within a Shader Storage Buffer to serve as an atomic counter
2. `image2D`

   - References a binding location for image data

You actually never modify the reference assigned to any opaque data type at shader run-time; hence they require `in` or `uniform` storage qualification. Instead, you pass the reference to a function that modifies the actual referenced resource (be it a texture or shader storage buffer).

You should be quite familiar with this paradigm already, `sampler2D`, for instance is probably the first opaque data type you ever used in GLSL. Such a uniform does not store the texture you are sampling, it stores the binding location for the texture/sampler state.

---

#### To answer your question:

They are "called uniforms" because shader invocations cannot change the reference that an `atomic_uint` or `image2D` stores. You can certainly modify the data referenced with the appropriate functions (*e.g.* `imageStore (...)` or `atomicCounterIncrement (...)`), but you cannot re-assign the reference itself.