# OpenGL uniform samplerBuffer: what does it point to?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I am trying to figure out what determines the buffer object that a `uniform samplerBuffer` points to.

Let us say we have `uniform samplerBuffer aBuffer` and its value is **0**; what does `aBuffer` point to?

Comment: Texture Image Unit 0; I answered a similar question recently, I will point you [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052164/why-are-atomic-counters-and-images-referred-as-uniforms-when-they-are-actually-n/24054265#24054265). But basically it references the texture bound to that image unit.

Comment: @Andon In other words it points to `GL_TEXTURE0`?

Comment: Yes, a `samplerBuffer` is no different from any other kind of sampler. Really the only unique thing here is the fact that you allocated the thing bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` in this example with `glTexBuffer (...)` rather than say `glTexImage2D (...)` (in the case of a `sampler2D`). Well, that and of course, the fact that you have to use `texelFetch (...)`.

Comment: @Andon wait, I didn't know that. What if you did bind something using `glTexImage2d()`?

Comment: Then it would not be a buffer texture. That is what this question is about, right? `glTexImage2D (...)` is for `GL_TEXTURE_2D` / `sampler2D`. `glTexBuffer (...)` is for `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` / `samplerBuffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how `aBuffer` knows which buffer object to fetch texel memory from?

`aBuffer` is a sampler (more precisely, a ***buffer sampler***), and it has the value **0** in this example, so it refers to the buffer texture (`GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`) that is currently bound to `GL_TEXTURE0`.

The association between the buffer texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` and the backing storage comes from the last parameter in the call to [`glTexBuffer (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexBuffer.xml). That last parameter is the name of a buffer object.

Comment: Ok, there's just one question. What if we did `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` and then `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, x)` (or any other target besides `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`) and then tried to access it through `uniform sampleBuffer`?

Comment: Each Texture Image Unit stores bindings to a set of ***separate*** targets: `GL_TEXTURE_1D`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_3D`, `GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`, `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`, `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY`, `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`, and `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE_ARRAY`. Binding something to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` on `GL_TEXTURE0` only affects samplers using 2D textures for Texture Image Unit 0 (e.g. `sampler2D`). `samplerBuffer` uses the texture bound to the target `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`, so is unaffected.

Comment: Ok, awesome, that's what I thought. I hope I'm not pushing it too much, but what is the difference between `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_DATA_STORE_BINDING` and `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_BUFFER` (in regards to a Texture Image Unit)?

Comment: The first one of those is the buffer object that the currently bound buffer texture uses (remember the last parameter in `glTexBuffer (...)`) and the second one is the buffer texture currently bound to to the active Texture Image Unit (e.g. `glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, ...)`)